# If Statement with multiple OR Values

Tags: c#, if-statement, textbox

I'm currently working on a Simple Riddles Game outside of class, and what I want to do is have a statement that will verify what the question is, and if the answer that was put in is correct. Here is the code I have so far:

```
private void butt_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lab_Riddle.Text == "What Walks on 4 Legs in the Morning, 2 in the Afternoon and 3 in the Evening?")

                if (TeBo_Ans.Text == "A Man") ;
;             {
                MessageBox.Show("Well Done");
                lab_Riddle.Text = ("I have an Eye but Cannot See- What Am I?");
             }
            if (TeBo_Ans.Text == "Mankind") ;
             {
                MessageBox.Show("Good Words");
                lab_Riddle.Text = ("I have an Eye but Cannot See- What Am I?");
             }
            if (TeBo_Ans.Text == "People") ;
             {
                MessageBox.Show("Yes");
                lab_Riddle.Text = ("I have an Eye but Cannot See- What Am I?");
             }
            if (TeBo_Ans.Text == "A Person") ;
             {
                MessageBox.Show("Exactly");
                lab_Riddle.Text = ("I have an Eye but Cannot See- What Am I?");
             }
            if (TeBo_Ans.Text == "Humankind") ;
             {
                MessageBox.Show("Exactly");
                lab_Riddle.Text = ("I have an Eye but Cannot See- What Am I?");
             }
        }
```

Here, `lab_Riddle` is the label containing the Question, and `TeBo_Ans` is the textbox the user types the answer into. This code sort of Works, but ideally I'd like to condense it down to something like

```
If lab_Riddle.Text= [Riddle 1]
 {
  If TeBo_Ans == [a] OR [b] OR [d] 
   {
    MessageBox.Show ("Correct")
    lab_Riddle.Text [riddle 2]
    }
   Else 
   { 
    MessageBox.Show ("Incorrect")
  }
}
```

Language is C# if I haven't already said, and vertical lines. This is probably a really long and convoluted way of doing this, but i'm still very new to coding.

Comment: you can use 'else if' just to not do all comparisons

Comment: Are you just looking for the `||` operator?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/

Comment: Also, your code has a pretty significant bug in it, so I don't see how it could be working *at all* in its current form.  Those semi-colons at the end of each of your `if` conditions are terminating your `if` blocks.  So all of your conditions are being ignored and all of your code blocks are executing.

Comment: Yeah, That does actually explain one of the issues i was having where every single answer was showing at once, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well you could use a dictionary for the answers

such as

```
    String answer = "a dog";
    Dictionary<string, string> riddleans = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    riddleans.Add("a man", "Well done");
    riddleans.Add("mankind", "Good words");
    answer = answer.ToLower();
    if (riddleans.ContainsKey(answer))
    {
        Messagebox.Show(riddleans[answer]);
        gotonextriddle();
    }
    else
    {
        Messagebox.Show("Incorrect);
    }
```

but you can expand on that by having either structure or class using that that you then have a list of riddles and so on.

One thing to point out here was the tolower of the answer - it means that instead of "Mankind" if I wrote "MANKIND" or "mankind" it all still fits.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have different pieces of text that you want to display depending on what the user is entering, you could store it in a `Dictionary`

```
var answers = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "Mankind", "Good words"  },
    { "People", "Yes" },
    { "A Man", "People" }
};

var answerGiven = TeBo_Ans.Text;

if (answers.ContainsKey(answerGiven))
{
    // user has the correct answer
}
```

Obviously in this instance you'd need to consider case sensitivity, for one, but it's just one way of doing what you want. I suppose in some ways your question may be better placed on the Code Review Stack Exchange.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/